# FB pixel not sending events to Google Analytics (GA4) while using tag manager

Tags: google-tag-manager, facebook-pixel, google-analytics-4, webflow

I'm really struggling connecting the FB pixel, my website, Google Tag manger, and GA4 analytics together. I am trying to track when different CTAs are clicked on the homepage. I have set that up with the FB pixel, however, can't seem to see those events in GA4. Here's what I have done:

1. FB pixel installed successfully with `fbq('track', 'EventName');` for each button
2. Google tag manager head and footer code inserted into homepage
3. FB pixel and GA4 tags set up in tag manager set to fire on #4 below
4. Link triggers set up for each button with click ID matching my button ID

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, and why GA4 isn't seeing which button is clicked!

Has anyone successfully greased this path? I imagine this may be difficult for marketers?  Any insight is greatly appreciated!! Thank you!

Site is oxandrabbitdesigns.com, hosted on webflow

Comment: The title of your question is somewhat confusing - why would the Facebook pixel send data to GA4? The FB pixel sends data to Facebook. Can you clarify?

Comment: @EikePierstorff Hey thanks for asking (and maybe what I'm doing isn't necessary?), but here is the end goal: I just want to see which CTA is being clicked as an event or conversion in GA4 and FB, for the sake of using FB ads, does that help clarify things a bit?

Comment: When I click your "subscribe"-Button I see two FB events fired (Lead and SubscribebuttonClick) but no GA events. So make sure you have a GA4 event tag that is connected to the same trigger as the FB events. Maybe you can share a few more details of how this is set up in GTM?

Comment: yep, that's correct—as far as GTM, i have 2 separate GA4 event tags set up with the measurement ID, and tied to separate triggers for each button, which are set up as "Click" -> "some links" -> Click ID = "corresponding-button-ID". I would think that from this I'd be able to see the event name in GA4 after the button is clicked, but that is not the case!